# Preg_match fails after rebuilding PHP

Tags: php, compilation, preg-match

I just tried to compile my PHP with php-soap. It seemed to build well, but now my website is showing the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Internal pcre_fullinfo() error -3
```

Im not sure if rebuilding my PHP without php-soap is going to work because that doesnt seem to be the problem by looking at the error. This is my php version:

```
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Sep  8 2012 16:09:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

This is my configuration:

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--with-apxs2' '--with-curl=/usr/local/lib' 
'--with-gd' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-ttf' '--with-gettext' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib' 
'--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-kerberos' '--with-openssl' 
'--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql=/usr' 
'--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr/local' 
'--with-pdo-mysql=/usr' '--with-pear' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib' 
'--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--enable-zip' 
'--with-iconv=/usr/local' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' 
'--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-soap' 
'--enable-mbstring'
```

Operating system is CentOS 5 with DirectAdmin

I really hope someone can help me with this. I can't find anything about this error on Google. And thank you very much in advance.

Comment: CentOS 5 and I am using DirectAdmin too btw

Comment: Try rebuilding without `--with-pcre-xxx=/usr/local`. You might link against an incompatible libpcre version. Try to use the system one, or the one bundled with php-src.

Comment: @mario, thank you, I tried that, but it walked into a ton of errors about references of the pcre library. I do not have to knowledge to remove those references. Three example errors:

1. usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/php-5.2.17/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:128: undefined reference to `pcre_version'
2. ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `zm_startup_pcre':
3. /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/php-5.2.17/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:154: undefined reference to `pcre_version'